# Wordpress Background won't change from color to tiled image?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The background in the HOME page has a stripe background but the Archive page doesn't? I tried changing the theme's default background in style.css

```
background-image : url('http://mangasaur.tk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/stripe_9cc72d60051c3cf7454f6e1c10a1d96d1.png');
background-repeat : repeat;
background-attachment : fixed;
```

But even with that it won't change!
I also edited the css of that archive page. It's a plugin for Wordpress (Kommiku) that has it's own CSS.

Kommiku CSS: http://pastebin.com/u7cFemfP

Website URL - http://mangasaur.tk/

Comment: @waygood Yes. The stripes are black and kinda dark gray.

Comment: There isn't a stripe in that image. It is 100% black.

Comment: Just double check and its completely black

Comment: If you check the website's home page then you can see it's striped. That's the same image I'm using.

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mangasaur.tk/wp-content/plugins/kommiku/themes/default/stylesheets/stylesheets/reset.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mangasaur.tk/wp-content/plugins/kommiku/themes/default/stylesheets/stylesheets/typography.css" -- this may be the reason.

Comment: @MarioP You typed stylesheets twice.

Comment: @creeperslayercraft - i didn't type anything - this is served by your archive page. There you have your problem.

Comment: @MarioP Where exactly? I double checked on the source of the archive page but I couldn't find those lines

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue in the http://www.mangasaur.tk/wp-content/themes/live-wire/style.css file :

Line 1:

> ... font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;} **body{background:#f2f2f2;** border-top:0.3125em ...

Seems like its a style sheet for a theme called live-wire.

Comment: It appears as this on my ftp client
`background-image:url('http://mangasaur.tk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/stripe_9cc72d60051c3cf7454f6e1c10a1d96d1.png');`
`background-repeat:repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

In file: http://www.mangasaur.tk/wp-content/plugins/kommiku/themes/default/stylesheets/main.css

Search:

```
@import url('stylesheets/reset.css');
@import url('stylesheets/typography.css');
```

Replace with:

```
@import url('reset.css');
@import url('typography.css');
```

The reason it works on the main page is that you include it in its own tag: `<style id="custom-background-css" type="text/css">...</style>` instead of including the main.css file, which isn't the case on the archive page.

Comment: Thanks! But, could you explain the last part? About the style thing. What can I do to fix that one?